How to handle "generic" time in Dart? (not tied to specific date)
My app matches users for a specific hobby. For that, users usually need to agree on a regular meeting time. For example "every Friday from 6pm to 10pm".
Storage wise I think I will go with a simple approach like described here: How can I store a time value, specifically only hour and minute in Firebase?
"monday":
{
    "start":
    {
        "hour": 7,
        "minute": 30
    },
    "duration":
    {
        "hour": 13,
        "minute": 30
    }
}

But now the question is, how do I use these in Dart/Flutter effectively to show "from to" times, without having to basically reconstruct the basic time calculation like this:
        var times = {
          // Weekday: [startHour, startMin, durationHour, durationMin]
          "Mo": [18, 00, 3, 30],
          "Tu": [18, 30, 4, 00],
        };

        var monday = times["Mo"];
        Text("User's schedule: 'Mo': ${monday![0]}:${monday[1]} - ${calculateEndHour()}");

This seems unnecessarily tedious.
Should I just construct them all as DateTime with the same fixed date? But then duration won't work properly.

You can try: https://pub.dev/packages/rrule

"This seems unnecessarily tedious." Then write a function to help you?

@jamesdlin That's what I ended up doing :) Just thought maybe I'm missing something that would make life easier.

I'm a timezone geek, so when I see "from 6pm to 10pm" I immediately wonder, "yeah, but whose version of 6pm??".  How are you handling timezones?

@RandalSchwartz I will be using UTC and display the timeZoneOffset explicitly, because that is a big part of this app for users to connect globally. Basically as described here.

Using the classes available in Dart/Flutter, this is how I would proceed (indeed, it is tedious, at least to write the first time, but at least it doesn't use some 1970-01-01 DateTime): you could use TimeOfDay class to store the (hour, minute) in the same object, I guess it would be a good start (there are not any calculation method available with this class, but this is what extension was made for). It would also make sense to store the "duration" in a Duration class. Doing so:
Given the extension methods:
extension TimeOfDayExtensions on TimeOfDay {
  TimeOfDay addDuration(Duration duration) {
    int totalInMinutes = minute + duration.inMinutes;
    int finalMinutes = totalInMinutes % 60;
    int hoursToAdd = (totalInMinutes - finalMinutes) ~/ 60;
    int finalHours = (hour + hoursToAdd) % 24;
    return TimeOfDay(hour: finalHours, minute: finalMinutes);
  }

  String display() {
    return "${hour < 10 ? "0" : ""}${hour.toString()}:${minute < 10 ? "0" : ""}${minute.toString()}";
  }
}

You can call it easily with:
TimeOfDay begin = TimeOfDay(hour: 18, minute: 00);
Duration duration = Duration(hours: 3, minutes: 30);
TimeOfDay end = begin.addDuration(duration);
Text("User's schedule: 'Mo': ${begin.display()} - ${end.display()}");


That's a lot more sophisticated than what I came up with, thank you!

@Big_Chair You're welcome, I had fun building it up. Note that you can easily enhance it to use the 12h AM/PM format if you wish to.
